# ESX Packet Loss

Tags: networking, vmware-esx

I'd like to test my software with some amount of packet loss.  I see that I can do this with pfSense in the traffic shaping.  But that's a lot of hassle to set up and create a couple of extra virtual switches and so on.

Can I do this directly in ESX to a particular network interface or across an entire virtual switch?

Comment: Are you really running ESX? If so, you really ought to consider updating. ESX was deprecated some time ago.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, no, ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this directly in ESX to a particular network interface or
>   across an entire virtual switch?

No. You'll need to route the traffic through a linux or BSD box to mangle the packets.

Answer (score 0):

As EEAA stated, nothing you can do specifically in ESX(i) to acomplish this, however...

There a fairly simple free tool called "WANEM" http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/jan/12/emulating-wans-wanem/

Basically you boot from the iso, setup an IP, configured your default route (client side) to the wanem IP, set your tcp parameter and away you go.